# Virtual machine not working after installing Docker-a hypervisor has been detected. features required for hyper-v will not be displayed

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, hypervisor

Virtual machine not working after installing Docker-a hypervisor has been detected. features required for hyper-v will not be displayed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLmPv.png)

I just installed docker desktop and started using it and my oracle virtual box is also not working.. when i see system information, I am getting below error.

```
hyper-v requirements: a hypervisor has been detected. features required for hyper-v will not be displayed
```

when i ran the below command in cmd and restart the PC. VM is working fine but docker desktop is not working.

```
bcdedit/set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

> Is it possible to run both my Virtual machine and docker desktop at the same time? Can you please help me to understand this scenario if this is not possible?

Comment: Only one hypervisor at a time can run on your system.  You can either have Hyper-V installed, or you can have VirtualBox installed. I am confused by your first image. I don't understand it's purpose.

Comment: @ramhound is it possible to use my oracle virtual box and docker desktop at the same time?

Comment: [Docker Desktop requires either WSL2 or Hyper-V](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) VirtualBox isn't compatible hypervisor.  If you do have Hyper-V running it's not clear the reason you would also need VirtualBox

Comment: The latest VMware is compatible with Hyper-V. But why not use Hyper-V?

Comment: Yes, you can run Hyper-V and VirtualBox at the same time per VirtualBox docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/hyperv-support.html